# Binding SolrNet query results to a GridView

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

Anyone know how to bind a SolrNet result set to a GridView control? I suspect it involves ObjectDataSource but I can't seem to get the right thing thrown together. Any help would be appreciated, I need this part done quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a SolrNet result set implements `IList<T>`, you can just bind to a GridView with a few `<asp:BoundField>`s (one for each property you want to bind) in the aspx, and passing the result object as DataSource before calling DataBind()

See also [Binding Gridview to IList<BusinessObject> that contains an IList<BusinessObject>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970741/binding-gridview-to-ilistbusinessobject-that-contains-an-ilistbusinessobject)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't know I could just mark the result set as a DataSource.